# how to call an Activity through TabBars

Tags: android

I'm making an application in which m using Tab Bars. 
Now what i need to know is, how to open other Tab through `setOnTabChangedListener()` in my code

for example. i am currently in tab and when i click on the 2nd tab it should call the activity of 2nd tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see the below code

```
 TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the Movies tab.
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BarActivity.class);
        // Initialise a TabSpec for the Movies tab and add it to the TabHost.
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Nights").setIndicator("Nights").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same things for the Theatres tab.
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BarActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Weeks").setIndicator("Weeks").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: i have don this thing but my code written in those activities are called only once when i open that application first. the second time when i click on another tab then i just displayes me the view reffered with it. how can i call the activity again..? please guide

Comment: do i need to add some more onRestart() method or onStart Method in that activity and put my code in that ?? please guide....

Comment: if u want to again start the activity finish the current activity when u press the other tab

Comment: You should implement the stuff you want to be called every time the tabs change in `onResume` instead of trying to hack the tab view to get it to do what you want.